# How to search a column in a html table and highlight any matches

Tags: jquery, html

Can some one help me out with a code snippet that will allow me to search one column on a html table with the search criteria that has been typed in to a text box? which would be a mobile number i want to be able to search the mobile phone number TD in my table provided below and highlight any matches.....

heres my button and txt box i want to call the jquery off the button click.........

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchMobileNumber" runat="server" CssClass="number"></asp:TextBox>

 <asp:button runat="server" id="BtnSearchMobile"\>
```

heres my table

```
    <code>
    <table id="HandsetDetails">
         <tr>
          <td>
             Mobile Phone number
             </td>
              <td>
              Network Provider
              </td>
              <td>
                Amount
              </td>
            </tr>
       </table>
</code>
```

Comment: Why are you searching an HTML table instead of, say, a table in a database?

Comment: because this HTML table is populated by the user, so they can add as many rows as they want, this search functionality will allow the user to search any row to quickly find the number they need to modify if they make a mistake etc

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery [highlight plugin](http://bartaz.github.com/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html)

```
$("#HandsetDetails").highlight(<your keyword(s)>);
```

then just create a CSS style for your highlighted word(s) :

```
.highlight {
    background-color: #FFFF88;
}
```

Using highlight with your HTML :

```
$('#BtnSearchMobile').click(function() {
    $("#HandsetDetails").highlight($('#txtSearchMobileNumber').val());
});
```

This uses [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

or even better you could use [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) another jQuery plugin that could filter the table depending on input - and a load more !! export to excel / pdf etc

(note - im not connected to either plugin - just hate re-inventing the wheel)

Comment: Thanks very much for the information, and example, i never new there was a highlight plugin im new to Jquery you see, so am i right in saying in the (<your keyword(s)>); would be the name of my textbox?

Comment: @ScottAtkinson add a section "Using hightlight with your HTML" to my answer - that should get you started .... really recommend a look at DataTables too - filtering will be better thatn trying to highlight something off the screen ....